# How do I make a long list of http calls in serial?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016

I'm trying to only make one http call at time but when I log the response from `getUrl` they are piling up and I start to get 409s (Too many requests)

```
function getUrl(url, i, cb) {
  const fetchUrl = `https://api.scraperapi.com?api_key=xxx&url=${url.url}`;

  fetch(fetchUrl).then(async res => {
    console.log(fetchUrl, 'fetched!');
    if (!res.ok) {
      const err = await res.text();
      throw err.message || res.statusText;
    }

    url.data = await res.text();
    cb(url);
  });
 }


let requests = urls.map((url, i) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    getUrl(url, i, resolve);
  });
});

const all = await requests.reduce((promiseChain, currentTask) => {
  return promiseChain.then(chainResults =>
    currentTask.then(currentResult => [...chainResults, currentResult]),
  );
}, Promise.resolve([]));
```

Basically I don't want the next http to start until the previous one has finished. Otherwise I hammer their server.

BONUS POINTS: Make this work with 5 at a time in parallel.

Comment: make the request and make it wait with await. since you make the request in a promise it all resolves at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `await`, it would be a lot easier to use that everywhere instead of using confusing `.then`s with `reduce`. It'd also be good to avoid the [explicit Promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). This should do what you want:

```
const results = [];
for (const url of urls) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(response); // or whatever logic you need with errors
  }
  results.push(await response.text());
}
```

Then your `results` variable will contain an array of response texts (or an error will have been thrown, and the code won't reach the bottom).

The syntax for an `async` function is an `async` keyword before the argument list, just like you're doing in your original code:

```
const fn = async () => {
  const results = [];
  for (const url of urls) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response); // or whatever logic you need with errors
    }
    results.push(await response.text());
  }
  // do something with results
};
```

To have a limited number of requests at a time, make a queue system - when a request completes, recursively call a function that makes another request, something like:

```
const results = [];
const queueNext = async () => {
  if (!urls.length) return;
  const url = urls.shift();
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(response); // or whatever logic you need with errors
  }
  results.push(await response.text());
  await queueNext();
}
await Promise.all(Array.from({ length: 5 }, queueNext));
// do something with results
```

Comment: it doesn't like the await fetch in the for loop

Comment: To use `await`, you have to be in an `async` function - make sure you're in an `async` function.

Comment: ok, this works but my vscode editor thinks its missing an async declaration.

Comment: Like I said, you need to put it in an `async` function, just like you're doing in your original code. Did you try doing that? It'll work.

Comment: yeah it works. its inside an async function but the editor just thinks its missing something. Oh well. I can live with this. Any idea how I would make this run 5 at a time in parallel? I know its not part of my original question. But this is taking a long time 2-3 seconds per request.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Array methods to sequentually run async operations because array methods are all synchronous.

The easiest way to achieve  sequential async tasks is through a loop. Otherwise, you will need to write a custom function to imitate a loop and run `.then` after a async task ends, which is quite troublesome and unnecessary.

Also, `fetch` is already returning a Promise, so you don't have to create a Promise yourself to contain that promise returned by `fetch`.

The code below is a working example, with small changes to your original code (see comments).

```js
// Fake urls for example purpose
const urls = [{ url: 'abc' }, { url: 'def', }, { url: 'ghi' }];

// To imitate actual fetching
const fetch = (url) => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({
      ok: true,
      text: () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(url), 500))
    });
  }, 1000);
});

function getUrl(url, i, cb) {
  const fetchUrl = `https://api.scraperapi.com?api_key=xxx&url=${url.url}`;
  return fetch(fetchUrl).then(async res => { // <-- changes here
    console.log(fetchUrl, 'fetched!');
    if (!res.ok) {
      const err = await res.text();
      throw err.message || res.statusText;
    }

    url.data = await res.text();
    return url; // <--- changes here
  });
}

async function getAllUrls(urls){
  const result = [];
  for (const url of urls){
    const response = await getUrl(url);
    result.push(response);
  }
  return result;
}

getAllUrls(urls)
  .then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` is perfect for this.

Assuming you have an array of URLs as strings:

```
let urls = ["https://example.org/", "https://google.com/", "https://stackoverflow.com/"];
```

You simply need to do:

```
for (let u of urls) {
  await fetch(u).then(res => {
    // Handle response
  }).catch(e => {
    // Handle error
  });
}
```

The loop will not iterate until the current `fetch()` has resolved, which will serialise things.

---

The reason `array.map` doesn't work is as follows:

```
async function doFetch(url) {
  return await fetch(url).then(res => {
    // Handle response
  }).catch(e => {
    // Handle error
  });
}
```

```
let mapped = urls.map(doFetch);
```

is equivalent to:

```
let mapped;
for (u of urls) {
  mapped.push(doFetch(u));
}
```

This will populate `mapped` with a bunch of `Promise`s immediately, which is not what you want. The following is what you want:

```
let mapped;
for (u of urls) {
  mapped.push(await doFetch(u));
}
```

But this is not what `array.map()` does. Therefore using an explicit `for` loop is necessary.

Comment: Is this specific to `for of`? I tried .map and it didn't work.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain the issue with `map()`.

Answer (score 0):

Many people provided answers using for loop. But in some situation `await` in for loop is not welcome, for example, if you are using Airbnb style guide.

Here is a solution using recursion.

```
// Fake urls for example purpose
const urls = [{ url: 'abc' }, { url: 'def', }, { url: 'ghi' }];

async function serialFetch(urls) {
  return await doSerialRecursion(
    async (url) => {
      return result = await fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
          // handle response
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          // handle error
        });
    },
    urls,
    0
  );
}

async function doSerialRecursion(fn, array, startIndex) {
  if (!array[startIndex]) return [];
  const currResult = await fn(array[startIndex]);
  return [currResult, ...(await doSerialRecursion(array, fn, startIndex + 1))];
}

const yourResult = await serialFetch(urls);
```

The `doSerialRecursion` function will serially execute the function you passed in, which is `fetch(url)` in this example.